# MS Excel - How to extend a formula dragging down for merged cells with different size

Tags: excel

In column A of sheet 1 in Microsoft Excel i have some merged cells. So for a example let say that A1 - A10 merged, A11 - A14 merged, A15-A21 merged.
I want to this cells to put a simple formula (=top_merged_cell+1). I will put the data to first merged cell by default (let it be 1000).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can make it with VBA macro:

```
Sub NumberOverMergedCells()
    first = 1
    last = 20
    col = "A"
    Cells(first, col) = 1
    k = 1
    For i = first + 1 To last
        Cells(i, col).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-" & k & "]C+1"
        If Cells(i, col) = "" Then
            k = k + 1
        Else
            k = 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

[image: Result]

You can avoid formulas at all:

```
Sub NumberOverMergedCells()
    first = 1
    last = 20
    col = "A"
    j = 1
    For i = first To last
        Cells(i, col) = j
        If Cells(i, col) <> "" Then
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```